# for i in xrange() not running the complete script

Tags: python

I have two sliders:

```
Sl_01 = cntrl[c4d.ID_USERDATA,13]/100
Sl_02 = cntrl[c4d.ID_USERDATA,15]/100
```

I want to move the Points from lists like this:

```
for i in xrange(len(thr_tip_init)):                

           pitch_list.append(pitch_dest - thr_tip_init)
           crest_list.append(crest_dest - thr_tip_init)

           pitchM_pos = Sl_01 * pitch_list + thr_tip_init
           thr_tip.SetPoint(i,pitchM_pos)

           crestM_pos = Sl_02 * crest_list + thr_tip_init
           thr_tip.SetPoint(i,crestM_pos)

           thr_tip.Message(c4d.MSG_UPDATE)
```

My problem is that it works but only the last script for the Sliders work, not both.

Comment: What's a slider? This question is very hard to answer without knowing what libraries you're using, what type each object is, etc

Comment: Sorry Kevin this is Python in Cinema 4d. I didn't get any answers from the C4d sites and thought maybe someone here can help me. a slider is a control that slides to change the values.In this case to move the vertices to new positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Eric.

This line of yours:

"Presumably the second call to thr_tip.SetPoint discards whatever changes were made on the for call"

put me on the right track. This is my new script and it works perfectly:

for i in xrange(len(thr_tip_init)):

```
    pitch_list.append(pitch_dest[i] - thr_tip_init[i])      
    crest_list.append(crest_dest[i] - thr_tip_init[i])

    pitchM_pos = Pitch * pitch_list[i] + thr_tip_init[i]           
    crestM_pos = Crest * crest_list[i] + pitchM_pos

    thr_tip.SetPoint(i,crestM_pos)

    thr_tip.Message(c4d.MSG_UPDATE)
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the second call to `thr_tip.SetPoint` discards whatever changes were made on the for call. Should one of the `thr_tip`s be a different variable?

Comment: the "thr_tip_init" is a list of the initial vectors of the points I want to move and stays the same. The "pitch_list" is the new vector list for the one slide control and "crest_list" the new vectors for the other slider.

Comment: I don't see how I can do two different point positions with only one variable?

Comment: Nor can I, which is why I think you should have another. What _is_ thr_tip?